# Spring boot @Column annotation on method instead of field?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to separate my class into smaller pieces by creating a Name object, but when I do the User Repository is having trouble finding the User from a String and seems like it wants a Name object.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserDTO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private Name name;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name.toString();
    }
```

```java
@Value
@Embeddable
public class Name {
    String name;
}
```

I want to be able to find the user using a String instead of the Name object, because I want the Name object to be isolated to the UserDTO class

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserDTO, UUID> {
    List<UserDTO> findAll(Pageable limit);
    UserDTO findByName(String name);
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [Name (n/a)]
```

Which I think is because the String does not match the Name object.

Answer (score 1):

There are many design issues in your code :

- You shouldn't use a `dto` class in your repository class, use an entity class instead. As a best practice, it should be used in your `Rest Controller` and map to your entity model before passing it to your `Service`. Take a look [here](https://auth0.com/blog/automatically-mapping-dto-to-entity-on-spring-boot-apis/).
- As you are using `UUID` the way you define the generation strategy should be different. Take a look [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/).
- There is no interest to you to wrap the name field into another type, as you can use it's *String* value and it contains only one field.
- Prefer the use of `@Column` annotation on your field instead of a getter method. It is just a personal choice. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028198/jpa-why-the-annotations-are-applied-on-getter-or-field).

Now to responde to your question, your error come from the fact that you return a `String` instead of a `Name` type.

Your classes could look something like this :

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Dto:

```
public class UserDto {

    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // Other getters and setters
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> {
    List<User> findAll(Pageable limit);
    User findByName(String name);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to combine multiple fields into one, like I might have a BasicUserInfo class which contains the name, the last name, the email, the password, but would want to be able to search up the user by the name without the rest of my code knowing about BasicUserInfo. In this case its only one field in Name, but I was hoping to be able to find users from nested information

Comment: I would like to avoid custom queries